# predict_proba for LinearSVC with CalibratedClassifierCV and cross_val_predict

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, cross-validation

I am trying to compute the accuracy and ROC for LinearSVM, but I'm not sure about getting probabilities for calculating ROC.

I have this for calculating the accuracy. y_pred gives me hard predictions.

```
svm = LinearSVC()
y_pred = cross_val_predict(svm, X, y, cv=5)
```

For calculating the probabilities, I have this:

```
clf = CalibratedClassifierCV(svm, cv=5)
scores = cross_val_predict(clf, X, y, cv=5, method='predict_proba')[:,1]
```

I am not sure of the above 2 lines because I feel like there is some repetition with the cv=5 parameter. Any ideas on how to combine cross_val_predict and CalibratedClassifierCV? I don't have a separate test set. **svm with linear kernel gives me different results, and I only want to use LinearSVM.**

Comment: Are you simply trying to train a model and determine auc and accuracy?  Why are you using `CalibratedClassifierCV()`?  Also, why don't you create a validation set?

Comment: I don't want to create another set. I only want to do cross-validation using cross_val_predict. Yes, I'm just training a model to determine the AUC and accuracy by cross-validating.